# how to reduce an array of objects in typescript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to turn this:

```
[{price: 30, date: 05}, {price: 60, date: 05}, {price: 40, date: 06}, {price: 70, date: 06}  ]
```

into this:

```
[{price: 90, date: 05}, {price 110, date: 06}]
```

Does anyone know how to do this in typescript? I keep getting the following error for trying to type the initial value:

```
  Types of parameters 'acc' and 'previousValue' are incompatible.
```

Here's what I tried:

```
  const reducedExpenses = expenses.reduce(
    (acc, { date, price }, index) => {
      if (acc[index].date === date) {
        return { ...acc[index], price: (acc[index].price += price) };
      }
      return acc.push({
        date,
        price,
      });
    },
    [{ date: -1, price: 0 }]
  );
```

Comment: So you're trying to sum `price` by `date`?

Comment: Why are your `date` properties [octal literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#octal_numbers)?

Comment: They were originally strings from Date objects but I converted them to octal literals to sort them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value) returns a number; the new length of the array. You're using this value as the accumulator.

What you're trying to do is most easily achieved by creating a map of *keys-to-sums* then transforming that map back into an array.

```js
const expenses = [{price: 30, date: 05}, {price: 60, date: 05}, {price: 40, date: 06}, {price: 70, date: 06}];

const priceSumByDate = expenses.reduce(
  (map, { price, date }) => map.set(date, (map.get(date) ?? 0) + price),
  new Map(), // TS Map<number, number>
);

const reducedExpenses = [];
priceSumByDate.forEach((price, date) => {
  reducedExpenses.push({ price, date });
});
console.log(reducedExpenses);
```

I've used a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) here instead of a plain object in order to preserve your (rather odd) [octal literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#octal_numbers) `date` properties without losing fidelity to string serialisation.

Comment: Thank you! They're written as octal literals so I could sort the dates without having to deal with the Date object

Answer (score 1):

You should always return an array, instead of returning an object in one branch and a number in another.

To simplify the code, you can start the accumulator as an empty array (giving `acc` an explicit type) and use `.at(-1)` to access the previous value.

```
const expenses = [{price: 30, date: 5}, {price: 60, date: 5}, {price: 40, date: 6}, {price: 70, date: 6}];
const reducedExpenses = expenses.reduce((acc: typeof expenses[number][], { date, price }) => {
    const prev = acc.at(-1);
    if (prev && prev.date === date) prev.price += price;
    else acc.push({date, price});
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: You could probably omit the `[]` initial value then you wouldn't need to check `prev`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant date to be a String, not an Octal constant:

```
 let arr = [{ price: 30, date: '05' },
    { price: 60, date: '05' },
    { price: 40, date: '06' },
    { price: 70, date: '06' }];
    
    let map = {}, group = [];
    arr.forEach(x => {
      map[x.date] = map[x.date] || (group[group.length] = { price: 0, date: x.date });
      map[x.date].price += x.price;
    });
    
    console.log(group);
```

Comment: From OP's comments, it seems intentional